# What is this part from an LCD monitor power supply?

Tags: power-supply, identification, components

A Samsung monitor (S32D850T) has this axial glass component on the power supply PCB. It was identified with a reference designator of “SA” and represented with a schematic icon on the back of the PCB that I did not recognize.

What is it?

[image: Component on top side of PCB]
[image: Component symbol on bottom side of PCB]

Comment: Sparkgap Arrestor.

Comment: Thank you! Why not make this an answer?

Comment: @TimWilliams - As we can't force someone to post an answer if they don't want to, I have posted an answer using that information and credited your comment.

Comment: @SamGibson I've entered, in my belief correct, but brief answers before, which promptly got flagged as "low quality". If there is no place for such a response in the comments nor in the answers, I would then guess the question should be closed for being unanswerable. If that's an incorrect impression I welcome instruction on the matter.

Comment: @TimWilliams - (a) [Comments are never for answering a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756). Doing so has several negative consequences. Even a short answer should be an *answer*. (b) I don't know which of your short answers was flagged - there are auto VLQ flags based on certain criteria, including very short answers, which should then be manually evaluated. It doesn't take much explanation to write a small paragraph on any topic, to avoid an auto VLQ (manual flags are always possible, of course - I don't know what happened in your case without more info from you).

Comment: (continued) Finally, this question is not unanswerable and it will not be closed for such an invalid reason. Please avoid posting strawmen like that, it can take an unreasonable amount of time for mods to explain things, if we have to knock down strawmen first. If there's a question, just ask it - don't invent speculative reasons why things are the way they are first. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @SamGibson , I'd just like to correct that that was just a supposition ("if...", "then I guess"), not a strawman. I take it then, those were incorrect impressions, and I thank you. I will defend such posts more confidently in the future. || I find the more subtle mechanisms of this site generally poorly explained or ambiguous; I rarely find meta questions addressing them, so I'm left to assume this is intentional (for flexibility, gaming avoidance, or good old plausible deniability). One consequence is, not knowing whether a function was user or auto/bot generated, for example.

Comment: @TimWilliams - Re: "*that was just a supposition {...} not a strawman.*" It's a strawman if you post supposition & assumptions, which I then have to take time to disprove / argue against etc. I *really* dislike that, as it wastes my limited time. This is also why I couldn't contribute to answering your [meta question](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9911) - too many assumptions that I disagreed with, but would take hours to address (I started to draft a reply, but it was still incomplete after 2 hours so I gave up - 2 hours wasted).

Comment: (continued) So please don't post suppositions & assumptions and then say "corrections welcome". It's a waste of your time guessing what assumptions to make, and would be a waste of my time disproving assumptions (I don't have time to try). That means you don't get the explanations you (presumably) want. So please don't do that. || You are not "left to assume" anything. Again, please don't guess reasons like "plausible deniability". That sounds like an accusation and *really* annoys me.

Comment: (continued) If you ask a short, straightforward question on our Meta (after searching our Meta & Meta.SE yourself) you are much more likely to get a straightforward answer. But if you muddy the question with guesses & assumptions, you will get fewer (if any) replies. || Re user or auto/bot generated (I guess you mean flags here) - post a short, clear Meta question, no assumptions, no guesses, no accusations, linking to a specific answer where you got flagged. I'll investigate and explain what happened. || No further comments here, please. These will all be deleted eventually.

Comment: @SamGibson I understand Tim’s position. I’m always a little reluctant to offer answers because SE can be hostile and pedantic. I appreciate your action. I also suggest you review your comments and notice how annoyed you sound. I don’t know if I’m misreading, but that’s the kind of public scolding that turns people off to SE. The irony the this seems like a public scolding not lost in me.

Comment: @SamGibson allow me to emphasize my appreciation and belief that you have the highest intention. And I apologize for going meta in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [commented](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/689916/what-is-this-part-from-an-lcd-monitor-power-supply#comment1838342_689916) by [Tim Williams](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/311631/tim-williams), the component designator "SA" is commonly used for "Sparkgap Arrestor".

Comment: As we can't force someone to post a proper answer if they don't want to, and since [comments should not be used to post answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756), I have applied the approach explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252303) to post someone else's comment as an answer. I have set the answer to "Community wiki" so that I don't earn any points from the answer.